# How could I assign the value from lua_tostring() to a variable in type of wstring or const wchar_t* in utf-8

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, lua

The type of the return value of the function `lua_tostring()` is `const char*`. However, I have a C Function that needs a string as a parameter. And the string will be Chinese in UTF-8 coding format.

```cpp
extern "C" LUALIB_API int PrintString(lua_State * L) {
    const char* str = lua_tostring(L, 1) // Get the string parameter 
                                         // And the string is actually in utf-8 in Lua.

    const WCHAR* str_w = .../* somehow makes str been an const WCHAR* */

    SomeFuncNeedWCHAR(str_w) // Imagine this func need a const WCHAR* as parameter. 

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using the `MultiByteToWideChar()`.

```
    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, NULL, -1);

    WCHAR* buffer = new wchar_t[size * sizeof(wchar_t)];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, buffer, size * sizeof(wchar_t));

    SomeFuncNeedWCHAR(buffer)

    delete[] buffer;
```

But I guess the str actually stores the char in UTF-8, after this conversion, it will convert a utf-8 to utf-8. (I mean, it convert twice). So I just want to find a way to interpret the return value from `lua_tostring()` to type `const WCHAR*`.

You basically could think the `SomeFuncNeedWCHAR()` has some similar behavior like `MessageBoxExW()` to show a message box in UTF-8.

So I am wondering how to approach that. Thank you!

Comment: `after this conversion, it will convert a utf-8 to utf-8.` - It's impossible.  `MultiByteToWideChar()` never converts to UTF-8.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I don't really understand how this function works. But on the doc, it says __"This function maps a character string to a wide-character (Unicode) string."__. Anyway, this function didn't work as I expect. But basically, I just want to pass the string from `lua_tostring()` as a parameter in the type of `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: `size * sizeof(wchar_t)` should just be `size`, other than that your code appears correct, could you explain more clearly what problem you are having?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank You. Basically, I just want to pass the return value of lua_tostring() to MessageBoxExW() as a parameter. It needed an `LPCWSTR`. And I try to use the `MultiByteToWideChar()` to convert the string to a wide char string. But the string value gets from lua_tostring is actually formatted in utf-8 in Lua. And the final result is some error codes on the message box after the conversion by `MultiByteToWideChar()`. So I just guess that it might convert one more time(not really sure)?

Comment: What is the error code? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles not error code, just random code or say garbled code. I try to make a minimal example now.

Comment: If that is all you need, call `MessageBoxExA` provided that your process/system is prepared to accept UTF-8 for the ANSI API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `MultiByteToWideChar()` correctly.

Specifically, you are setting its `cchWideChar` parameter to `-1` on the 1st call, when it needs to be `0` instead:

> `cchWideChar`
>
> Size, in characters, of the buffer indicated by `lpWideCharStr`. **If this value is 0, the function returns the required buffer size, in characters, including any terminating null character, and makes no use of the `lpWideCharStr` buffer.**

And even if it would succeed, you are over-allocating the `buffer`, which is not strictly an error, but it is wasting unused memory.

Try this instead:

```cpp
extern "C" LUALIB_API int PrintString(lua_State * L) {
    const char* str = lua_tostring(L, 1);

    int str_len = strlen(str) + 1; // avoid MBTWC() from needing to re-calculate the
                                   // same string length multiple times. Also include
                                   // the null terminator in the output...

    int w_len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, str_len, NULL, 0);

    WCHAR* str_w = new WCHAR[w_len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, str_len, str_w, w_len);

    SomeFuncNeedWCHAR(str_w);

    delete[] str_w;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank You! it finally solves my problem perfectly. I used to think the `cchWideChar` should pass `-1` by default like how does for the `cbMultiByte`.

Comment: @YZS Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar). `cchWideChar` does not support `-1` at all, only `>= 0`.

Comment: @yzs `cchWideChar` describes the output buffer. The API cannot know, calculate, or guess its length. It must trust you. That's different from input parameters, like `cbMultiByte`, where the API *can* calculate the length of the input string, provided that it is NUL terminated.